# For an ideal $J$ is it true that $J \circ J = J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

My question is pretty straightforward.

> If for a ring $\left({R, +, \circ}\right)$ we have an [ideal](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aIdeal_%28Ring_Theory%29) $J$, is it true that $J \circ J = J$?

In other words
$\forall j \in J \quad \exists j_1,j_2 \in J \colon j_1 \circ j_2 = j. $

---

I got this idea from the [quotient rings](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition%3aQuotient_Ring) because the definition $\forall x,y: \left({x + J}\right) \circ \left({y + J}\right) := \left({x \circ y}\right) + J$ would be very elegant if one could think about the pairwise "multiplication" of $\left({x + J}\right) \circ \left({y + J}\right)$, however it only makes sense if $J \circ J = J$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiplication of ideals $IJ$ is the ideal generated by elements $xy$ where $x\in I$ and $y\in J$.

Hence, the answer is no. Think of $x\notin (x)(x)=(x^2)\subseteq k[x]$. Or $2\notin(2)(2)=(4)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$.

Usually, you just get an inclusion $I^2\subseteq I$.

Comment: Could you please add a little remark about the definition of your ideals? Differences in notation used worldwide confused me.

Comment: @Pranasas Does the edit help?

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I meant like $(2)(2) = \{2 \cdot 2 \cdot k \mid k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a ring with zero multiplication: $x\circ y=0$ for all $x,y\in R$. Then every subgroup $S$ of the additive group $R(+)$ is an ideal, and $S\circ S=0$.

Comment: This is a nice one. Assuming of course that the his definition of a ring does not include an unity. Even then you can easily modify it.

Comment: @LASV: Yes, of course.